# Pass long[] instead of Long

Tags: java

I have a function like this

```
void doSmth(Long... paramg){
}
```

But I can't pass `long[]` instead of `Long...`. Why? I thought it's the same things (whats the difference between them?).

**How can I pass long[] instead of Long... ?**

Comment: long is a primitive type and Long is a class. Autoboxing makes them seem almost identical, but arrays are not autoboxed. So just pass a `Long []`.

Comment: @GregS thanks. Looks like I've expected too much )

Comment: @biovamp Autoboxing for arrays just can't work, without significant overhead, which isn't a good thing to do implicitly because people may expect it to be magically more efficient than it can be. You'll either have to change the signature or create a new array and loop through it manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`long` can be [autoboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to `Long`, not the array (`long[]`)

for `long[]` to work it should be

```
void doSmth(long... paramg){
}
```